# How to connect components of an RC (and rPi) car to the battery safely?

Tags: pi-zero-w, battery, servo, dc-motor, design

I am building an RC car from scratch. I have a 6v motor with an appropriate mdb, a 5v hobby servo, a raspberry pi zero w, and an 2200mAh 11.1v 50 C battery. I will upgrade the motor to a higher voltage later which is why I am using the battery I am. The software I can handle on my own. Unfortunately circuit design is difficult for me.

I believe I need to connect these components in parallel to the battery. Correct me if I am wrong but I think the battery I am using can safely handle the discharge rate. My question is, in order to control the current so I don't fry anything, is a voltage regulator like the L4940V5 sufficient for each of the devices? Do I need something more robust? Am I missing some information?

Answer (score 1):

I would use one or more UBECs (Universal Battery Eliminating Circuit).  Use more than one if needed to supply the total current or different voltages.

A UBEC converts a voltage in the range 6-27V (depending on its specs) to 5V or 6V (depending on its specs).

They are fairly inexpensive and are widely used for your sort of application.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_eliminator_circuit